# A prolog program for identifying terms of the first order logic

Tags: prolog

I am developing a prolog program to identify terms of the first order logic, which are constants (c1, c2, c3, ...), variables (v1, v2, v3, ...), and lists of the form [fsymbol, t1, t2, ..., tn], where fsymbol is a function symbol (f1a1, f2a1, f3a1, ..., f1a2, f2a2, f3a2, ...), t1, t2, t3, ..., tn are terms of the first order logic and n (the number of entries in [t1, t2, ..., tn]) is the arity of the function fsymbol (indicated after the 'a', in the name of the function: e.g., f4a6 has arity 6, f1a3 has arity 3, etc). I wanted to define a predicate term/1 that succeeds if the argument is a term of the first order logic. I was able to do it only after I enclosed each variable and each constant in a singleton list, so that [c1] is a term, but c1 is not. When I try to redefine the predicate term/1 in order to enable arguments that may be atoms (not lists), I get the following error message:

> ERROR: Type error: `atomic' expected, found` [v1]' (a list)

This code works well, except by not recognizing v1, v2, ..., c1, c2, ... as terms; it only accepts [v1], [v2], ..., [c1], [c2], etc.

```
onlyDigits([]). %Empty lists has only digits as elements, vacuously.
onlyDigits([A|L]) :- A>=48,A=<57,onlyDigits(L). 
intPos(L) :- length(L,X),X>0,onlyDigits(L),name(N,L),N>0. %Verifies whether the list L converts to a string that represents a positive integer.
letterNumber(Ascii,LN) :- name(LN,[Ascii|L]),intPos(L). %Verifies whether the list LN has precisely a letter (corresponding to the ASCII code Ascii) followed by digits.
variable(V) :- letterNumber(118,V). %v1, v2, v3, etc.
constant(C) :- letterNumber(99,C).  %c1, c2, c3, etc.
function(F) :- function(F,_).       %f1a1, f2a1, f1a2, f2a2, etc.
function(F,A) :- name(F,L),append([102|L1],[97|L2],L),intPos(L1),intPos(L2),name(A,L2).
term([T|L]) :- variable(T), L==[].
term([T|L]) :- constant(T), L==[].
term([T|L]) :- function(T,A),length(L,A),listOfTerms(L,A),!.
listOfTerms([],0).
listOfTerms([T|L],Q) :- Q>0,term(T),Q2 is Q-1,listOfTerms(L,Q2).
listOfTerms(L) :- length(L,Q),listOfTerms(L,Q).
```

The next code does not work well (I get that error message).

```
onlyDigits([]). %Empty lists has only digits as elements, vacuously.
onlyDigits([A|L]) :- A>=48,A=<57,onlyDigits(L).
intPos(L) :- length(L,X),X>0,onlyDigits(L),name(N,L),N>0. %Verifies whether the list L converts to a string that represents a positive integer.
letterNumber(Ascii,LN) :- name(LN,[Ascii|L]),intPos(L). %Verifies whether the list LN has precisely a letter (corresponding to the ASCII code Ascii) followed by digits.
variable(V) :- letterNumber(118,V). %v1, v2, v3, etc.
constant(C) :- letterNumber(99,C).  %c1, c2, c3, etc.
function(F) :- function(F,_).       %f1a1, f2a1, f1a2, f2a2, etc.
function(F,A) :- name(F,L),append([102|L1],[97|L2],L),intPos(L1),intPos(L2),name(A,L2).
term(T) :- variable(T).
term(T) :- constant(T).
term(T) :- T = [T1|L1],function(T1,A),length(L1,A),listOfTerms(L1,A),!.
listOfTerms([],0).
listOfTerms([T|L],Q) :- Q>0,term(T),Q2 is Q-1,listOfTerms(L,Q2).
listOfTerms(L) :- length(L,Q),listOfTerms(L,Q).
```

What is the problem here? Is it the fact that the predicate term is being used both with atoms and with lists as arguments?

---

*Edit*: Some examples of how I want my program works:

```
?- term(f2a1).
false.

?- term([f2a1, v1]).
true.

?- term(v1).
true.

?- term([f2a2, v1]).
false.

?- term([f2a2, v1, v2]).
true.

?- term([f2a3, v1, v2, [f10a1, c11]]).
true.

?- term([f2a3, v1, v2, [f10a1]]).
false.

?- term([f1a2, [f1a1, v4], [c1]]).
false.

?- term([f1a2, [f1a1, v4], c1]).
false.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can solve your problem, using SWI-Prolog, based on the following code:

```
isdigit(Char) :-
    Char @>= '0',
    Char @=< '9'.

alldigits(ListOfChars) :-
    maplist(isdigit, ListOfChars).

constant(Atom) :-
    atom_chars(Atom, [c|Rest]),
    alldigits(Rest).

variable(Atom) :-
    atom_chars(Atom, [v|Rest]),
    alldigits(Rest).

function(Atom) :-
    atom_chars(Atom, [f|Rest]),
    once(append(Prefix, [a|Suffix], Rest)),
    alldigits(Prefix),
    alldigits(Suffix).

term(Atom) :-
    once( (   constant(Atom)
          ;   variable(Atom)
          ;   function(Atom) ) ).

list_of_terms(List) :-
    maplist(term, List).
```

Some examples:

```
?- include(constant, [c12, v345, c6, f7a2, v89, f103a5], R).
R = [c12, c6].

?- include(variable, [c12, v345, c6, f7a2, v89, f103a5], R).
R = [v345, v89].

?- include(function, [c12, v345, c6, f7a2, v89, f103a5], R).
R = [f7a2, f103a5].

?- list_of_terms([c12, v345, c6, f7a2, v89, f103a5]).
true.
```

**UPDATED** Considering the changes in the question:

```
isdigit(Char) :-
    Char @>= '0',
    Char @=< '9'.

alldigits(ListOfChars) :-
    maplist(isdigit, ListOfChars).

constant(Atom) :-
    atom(Atom),
    atom_chars(Atom, [c|Rest]),
    alldigits(Rest).

variable(Atom) :-
    atom(Atom),
    atom_chars(Atom, [v|Rest]),
    alldigits(Rest).

function([Atom|Args]) :-
    atom(Atom),
    atom_chars(Atom, [f|Rest]),
    once(append(Prefix, [a|Suffix], Rest)),
    alldigits(Prefix),
    alldigits(Suffix),
    number_chars(Arity, Suffix),
    length(Args, Arity),
    list_of_terms(Args).

term(Term) :-
    once( (   constant(Term)
          ;   variable(Term)
          ;   function(Term) ) ).

list_of_terms(List) :-
    maplist(term, List).
```

Examples:

```
?- term(c123).
true.

?- term(v4).
true.

?- term([f56a2, c1, v3]).
true.

?- term([f56a7, c1, v3]).
false.

?- term([f46a3, v1, c2, [f1a4, v3, v3, v4, c6]]).
true.

?- term([f46a3, v1, c2, [f1a4, v3, v3, v4]]).
false.
```

Comment: [c12, v345, c6, f7a2, v89, f103a5] is not a list of terms, because the functions must be accompanied with the corresponding arguments. A list of terms would be, for example,
[c12, v345, c6, [f7a2, v1, [f1a1, c1]], v89, [f103a5, v2, c63, [f2a2, v1, c2], v3, v3]].

Comment: Please, see the edit in my post, with examples.

Comment: @JoãoJúnior I've updated my answer, according with the changes in the question.

Comment: I didn't change the question. I just explained it better. Anyway, your new answer is welcome.

Comment: your rules for variable and constant are the same. Did you miss something?

Comment: @JoãoJúnior, No, they are not the same! Notice that a constant is an atom expanded into a list starting with ```c``` (i.e., ```atom_chars(Atom, [c|Rest])```), while a variable is an atom expanded into a list starting with ```v``` (i.e., ```atom_chars(Atom, [v|Rest])```),.

Comment: @ Oh, I didn't notice the difference: one is with c, the other is with v!

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the program, with the predicate is_list/1:

```
onlyDigits([]).
onlyDigits([A|L]) :- A>=48,A=<57,onlyDigits(L).
posInt(L) :- length(L,X),X>0,onlyDigits(L),name(N,L),N>0.
letterNumber(Ascii,LetraNum) :- name(LetraNum,[Ascii|L]),posInt(L).
variable(V) :- letterNumber(118,V).%v1, v2, v3, etc.
constant(C) :- letterNumber(99,C). %c1, c2, c3, etc.
function(F) :- function(F,_),!.    %f1a1, f2a1, f1a2, f2a2, etc.
function(F,A) :- name(F,L),append([102|L1],[97|L2],L),posInt(L1),posInt(L2),name(A,L2),!.
term([T|L]) :- function(T,A),length(L,A),listOfTerms(L,A),!.
term(X) :- not(is_list(X)),variable(X),!;not(is_list(X)),constant(X),!.
listOfTerms([],0).
listOfTerms([T|L],Q) :- Q>0,term(T),Q2 is Q-1,listOfTerms(L,Q2).
listOfTerms(L) :- length(L,Q),listOfTerms(L,Q).
```

Examples:

?- term([f1a3, v1, [f1a1, v2], c3]).
true.

?- term([f2a2, f1a1]).
false.

?- term([f2a2, [f1a1]]).
false.

?- term([f2a2, [f1a1, v54]]).
false.

?- term([f2a2, [f1a1, v54], c0]).
false.

?- term([f2a2, [f1a1, v54], c462]).
true.

?- term(v1).
true.

?- term(c2).
true.

?- listOfTerms([v1, c2, [f1a4, v3, v3, v4, c6]]).
true.

?- term([f46a3, v1, c2, [f1a4, v3, v3, v4, c6]]).
true.